# Count number of blank cells in row between last cell and next non-blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Is it possible (with a formula preferably) to count the number of blank cells in row, where the counting starts at a given column and counts going backward (e.g. right to left) the number of blank cells until a non-blank cell is found?  In the example below, the counting begins at Column H and proceeds leftward.  Using `COUNTA` or `COUNTIF` seem like reasonable tools to use, but I am unsure on how to terminate the counting once a non-blank cell is found.

[image: excel screen shot count blank cells until non-blank]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this if the values in your table are all text:

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(CHAR(97+MATCH("zzzz",B2:H2))&ROW()&":H"&ROW()))
```

`MATCH("zzzz",B2:H2)` returns the column number in which the last non-blank cell is.

`CHAR(97+ column number)` returns the letter of that column.

Append it to the row number to give the reference where the `COUNTBLANK` has to start with `&ROW()`

`&":H"&ROW())` gives the reference of the last cell, which is `H` plus the row number.

`INDIRECT` turns the concatenated text into a range that Excel can evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

`=COLUMNS(B2:H2)-MATCH("zzzz",B2:H2)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested if statements

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2),IF(ISBLANK(G2),IF(ISBLANK(F2),IF(ISBLANK(E2),IF(ISBLANK(D2),IF(ISBLANK(C2),IF(ISBLANK(B2),IF(ISBLANK(A2),8,7),6),5),4),3),2),1),0)
```